# php form doesn't work on IE

Tags: php, forms, internet-explorer

I have a php form on my website and it works well under firefox.  But whenever I tested on IE(v8 and 9), the form doesn't get sent, and it returns a "IE can't display the webpage" error.

The script is located at http://www.fitnessgrace.com/Vancouver-Personal-Trainers/Vancouver-Personal-Trainers-Contact-Fitness-Grace.htm

Any insights would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

you are posting the page to `http://www.FitnessGrace.com/gdform.php`

and you have a hidden input

```
 <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="../index.html" />
```

after this point, **I can only guess**, but I think you are trying to redirect to "../index.html", and since `gdform.php` is already at the root directory, `../` is meaningless. I think firefox somehow understands that you've made a mistake and doesn't care, but ie doesn't understand.

Comment: Thanks Marvin!  It makes total sense!